# MVC3 @Html.EditorForModel NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm seeing and odd exception and completely out of ideas on how to resolve this.  I'm sure I'm overlooking something very obvious.  I had the following view work but did something and now cannot figure out why it suddenly stopped.

```
// All in an Area

// Controller
public ViewResult Test()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Test(TestModel testModel)
{
    // Do some work
    // Redirect or
    return View(testModel);
}

// Model
public class TestModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// View
@model MyApp.Areas.Admin.Models.TestModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create New User";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@section HeadSection {
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/MvcMembership.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}

<h2 class="someclass">Test Form</h2>

<div class="otherclass">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "MyController"))
    { 
    @Html.EditorForModel()
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
} 
</div>
```

I receive the following exception at @Html.EditorForModel() on the HttpGet in my actual code or in tests controllers/views.

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=App_Web_field.master.5f132152.av8tutrk
  StackTrace:
       at ASP.views_inputbuilders_editortemplates_field_master.__Render__control1(HtmlTextWriter __w, Control parameterContainer) in http://server/Views/InputBuilders/EditorTemplates/Field.Master:line 5
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException:
```

Any thoughts would be GREAT!!! -- Jeff

[Edit]  Few bullets:

- I have a working solution/project with test code.  The major difference is project size.  This is a big project with lots of areas, controllers, models and views.  So routing, references, etc... are different.  I have even stepped through and confirmed Model is null and with what little reading I can find it appears EditorFor[Model] uses reflections to create fields so it is something else.
- I found a working example online while searching for solution: http://mvcmembership.codeplex.com/

Comment: a: did you pass in a non-null `TestModel` as the model? b: what editor is it using? a default one? a custom one? what?

Comment: Both non-null and null.  TestModel is the model.  I'm using VS2010.  See my question edits above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had removed a portable area using MvcContrib.Mvc3-ci (v3.0.90.0) Nuget Package however did not remove usages in the Global.asax.cs file in the Application_Start().  In short I removed MvcContrib altogether and it works fine.  If I add the package and the Global.asax.cs usage and the issue returns.  When I have a moment I'll do a bit more to understand the issue, write a blog with the details and submit issues if necessary.

With the MvcContrib.Mvc3-ci (v3.0.90.0) installed, the Global.asac.cs file contained:

```
using MvcContrib.PortableAreas; // REMOVED THIS!

protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

    PortableAreaRegistration.RegisterEmbeddedViewEngine(); // REMOVED THIS!
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Thank to Maess, Darin and Michal for your help.  Can't mark any answers as correct but at the very least I can extend this thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You use EditorForModel and you pass a null reference to it. Fix it by sending e.g. a new TestModel object to the view from the controller.

Comment: Thanks Michal, I did find the solution which I highlighted at the bottom of the question.  I was sure it had to do with the project so might not have been a fair question.  Best -- Jeff

Answer (score 0):

```
public ViewResult Test()
{
    return View(new TestModel());
}
```

Comment: That does not solve the issue.  I've even stepped through it and I have no idea what is null.  I have a new solution and new project that works with exact same code.  I also found in searching for solution other similar code which works.  See question edits.

Comment: Thanks Darin, I did find the solution which I highlighted at the bottom of the question.  I was sure it had to do with the project so might not have been a fair question.  Best -- Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but, if you are sending in a new TestModel, I bet the Name property is null, try using a member which is always set to at least string.Empty to hold the Name property and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Thanks Maess, I did find the solution which I highlighted at the bottom of the question.  I was sure it had to do with the project so might not have been a fair question.  Best -- Jeff